# Regex in HTML Input pattern isn't working, but the expression is valid

Tags: html, regex

I have a URL input field on a form, and this must accept only Youtube and Vimeo URLs. I got a regex like this:

```
(?:(?i)(?:https:|http:)?\/\/)?(?:(?i)(?:www\.youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|watch\?v=)|youtu\.be\/|youtube\.googleapis\.com\/v\/)(?<YoutubeID>[a-z0-9-_]{11,12})|(?:vimeo\.com\/|player\.vimeo\.com\/video\/)(?<VimeoID>[0-9]+))
```

And it works. Tested here: https://regex101.com/r/PVdjg0/2

But when i have inserted this pattern on my field, it doesn't work. My field are aceppting any URL.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type='url' required pattern='(?:(?i)(?:https:|http:)?\/\/)?(?:(?i)(?:www\.youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|watch\?v=)|youtu\.be\/|youtube\.googleapis\.com\/v\/)(?<YoutubeID>[a-z0-9-_]{11,12})|(?:vimeo\.com\/|player\.vimeo\.com\/video\/)(?<VimeoID>[0-9]+))' title='URL Vimeo/Youtube.' name='video' placeholder='Video URL' />
            <input type='submit'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And i don't know why! I miss something? Somebody can help me?

Comment: here is yuor regx in JS https://regex101.com/r/NWkIGZ/1

Comment: Try it without the `(?i)` and use `/i` case insensitive flag https://regex101.com/r/8i6ruU/1 and `https:|http:` can be shortened to `https?:`